# MPLABx what does this error mean?

Tags: c, for-loop, target, mplab

Could somebody give me a hint about errors I get in MPLABX ver. 3.05
Compiler xc16 ver 1.24

> nbproject/Makefile-XC16_24FJ256GA110.mk:277: recipe for target
>   'dist/XC16_24FJ256GA110/production/Proximity_PIC24F_ver2.X.production.hex'
>   failed make[2]: Leaving directory
>   'D:/MpLabx3_05_projekty/Proximity_PIC24F_ver2/Proximity_PIC24F_ver2.X'
>   nbproject/Makefile-XC16_24FJ256GA110.mk:78: recipe for target
>   '.build-conf' failed make[1]: Leaving directory
>   'D:/MpLabx3_05_projekty/Proximity_PIC24F_ver2/Proximity_PIC24F_ver2.X'
>   nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
>   build/XC16_24FJ256GA110/production/main.o(.text+0x2): In function
>   `.LSM1': : undefined reference to`_SysBoardInit'
>   build/XC16_24FJ256GA110/production/main.o(.text+0x96): In function
>   `.LSM11': : undefined reference to`_SysLogInit'

Comment: Undefined references are messages that means you are missing some function or variable definition. Do you link with all object files or libraries you need? Did you forget to define a variable or function (i.e. implement it, not just declare it)?

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add a whole file system.c. Only had system.h
Heh, those mistakes... :)

Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

You called a function called SysBoardInit that cannot be found. Try including the c code with that function in it to the project.